# Proc.Start() ignoring WorkingDirectory on IIS

Tags: c#, iis, process, path

```
        public static void EseguiOttimizzatore(String path, string filename)
    {
        Process proc = new Process();
        proc.StartInfo.FileName = path + "nst.exe";
        proc.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = path;
        proc.StartInfo.Arguments = filename;
        proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;

        try
        {
            proc.Start();              
        }
        catch(FileNotFoundException e)
        {
            GLogWriter.Write("Eseguibile non trovato, copiare l'eseguibile dalla cartella lib a bin", LogCategories.Business, NstTraceEventType.Critical);
            throw e;
        }
        proc.WaitForExit();
        proc.Close();
    }
```

When I'm using my application in debug mode or in my local computer it works fine but if I run it on the production server IIS find my costum path (the variable `path`) but my exe runs in the directory `C:\Windows\system32\inetsrv\` ignoring my `path`.

Am I missing something?

Comment: what you mean with ignoring my path do you mean he try to execute the file somewhere else or

Comment: yes exactly. it ignores my path and uses the iis exec directory

Comment: Did you checked the path if path come from another process maybe he have also the wrong inherited path? are u sure that the path has the correct directory? Do something like GLogWriter.Write("Current executing path " + path);